# Is it possible to have a folder that only certain programs can write to?

Tags: windows, security

I have an application which generates some data files and exports them to a folder. It is very important that no-one can then edit these files - they should be able to read them but not update them/add more files to the directory.

Is it possible to somehow lock that directory so that only my application can write to it? I'm using windows 7, but a solution for XP and above would be excellent!

### Update

One potential solution I have found is:

- Creating a new user account and making it the only user that can write to the file
- Telling users to run my program as the other user

This would probably achieve what I'm looking for but it involves users having to type in a username/password again which isn't ideal, and also if they know the username/password of the user that has access to that folder then surely that isn't very secure! Is there any other way of doing this?

Also, the program that creates the data files is not my creation, so I have no access to the source code.

### Update 2

The program is an image analysis system - it calculates a whole load of values from a set of  images and then the user can export the results files into a folder. These results files are just plain tab delimited text files. It is just a 'normal' application and does not run as a service. As far as what environment we are in - we are in a 'workgroup' environment, but the solution would have to work in a standalone or domain environment too.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to import these files into a piece of software that I have written, without the possibility of the files being edited - so I am guaranteed to be looking at the 'raw' unedited data.

Comment: What have you researched or tried on your own so far? Details about the program and any attempted resolutions will result in a more accurate answer.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: You should still provide some more details. What application is it? Or what type of app, at least? What environment are you in: domain, workgroup, standalone machine? Is the application running as a service (like MS SQL does)? If so, it's easy to make it run as a separate user and assign privileges exclusively to that user. It's difficult to provide you with an answer if we have so many unknown variables.

Comment: How does your update prevent, for example, the OS installing files which requires access to the TEMP folder... Many programs require access to the App Data folder or to the temp folder - by preventing this you may stop the application working as it's supposed too... You'd be better off encrypting or password protecting the files instead of trying to force every application to abide by this rule?

Comment: You can easily avoid user interaction by creating a custom [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). Anyway, I agree with Erathiel: you should provide further information.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated the answer - hopefully this gives you the details you need!